Correlation between two Gaussian Processes
I have a space-time series, so it is in 2D. So, the signal model $\mathbf{S}$ is a matrix. If I fix the space, the time series at that point in space is a complex GP:
$$ \mathbf{S}[x, :]  \sim \mathcal{CGP}(0, \mathbf{C}_x), $$
where $\mathbf{C}_x$ is the kernel of the time series at point $x$, the kernel is:
$$ \mathbf{C}_x(t, t^{'}) = P_x \exp(-1/2 (t-t')^2 \sigma_x^2) \exp(-j (t-t') \mu_x )$$
I assume that the parameters $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$ are parameters that are spatial functions.
Then, how to find the total covariance structure with space as well so that I can use GP regression later? So, the covariance should be of the dimension ($MN \times MN$), where $M$ is the number of spatial points and $N$ is the number of time points.
Will this covariance be stationary anymore? I tried deriving the new kernel. Let's take two spatial points (at $x_1$ and $x_2$) and two-time points (at $t_1$ and $t_2$) and find the correlation:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{S}[x_1, t_1] \times \mathbf{S}[x_2, t_2]^{*} \right] $$
Should it be:
$$ P_{x_1} P_{x_2}\exp(-1/2(t_1^2 \sigma_{x_1}^2+ t_2^2 \sigma_{x_2}^2) \exp(-j (t_1 \mu_{x_1} - t_2 \mu_{x_2})) ? $$
Or is it easier to formulate if I assume $\mu_x$ and  $\sigma_x$ are also GPs but in space. I can assume it actually, but I need to see what kernel functions I can use for these. A better function to model these in space would be polynomials. So the idea is to estimate the parameters of $\mu_x$ and  $\sigma_x$ to reconstruct the profiles of both in space. It avoids the need to estimate $\mu_x$ and  $\sigma_x$ for each $x$ separately (by using GP regression in time for each x). The advantage would be just to estimate a few parameters that can explain the profiles of $\mu_x$ and  $\sigma_x$ in space.
$$ \mu_x = f(\Theta_\mu; x), $$
$$ \sigma_x = g(\Theta_\sigma; x) $$
The objective then should be to find
$$ [\Theta_\mu , \Theta_\sigma] = \max_{[\Theta_\mu , \Theta_\sigma]} \log(p(\mathbf{S} + \mathbf{N} | \Theta_\mu, \Theta_\sigma) ), $$
where $N$ is a noise matrix which is known.
